# Calculate number of vertices on shortest.paths igraph

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path, transport

Having a weighted directed network such as this:

```
library(igraph)

g <- erdos.renyi.game(25, 1/10, directed = TRUE)
E(g)$weight <- runif(length(E(g)), 1, 5)
```

When running the shortest path function `sp <- shortest.paths(g)`, I obviously get a matrix with the sum of the weighed edges in between. However, I would like to count how many vertices are on that path.

The idea comes from searching for the shortest paths for a train network, with the edges as train stations, being that I would like to see the amount of transfers (in between vertices or nodes), for each shortest path.

EDIT: For example if a shortest path is A to C, I want to know how many vertices are in between. For example if the full path is A - E - B - C, then the E and B are the intermediate vertices so I would have a value of 2. The full vertices path is ok as well, so in this case it would give me 4 vertices for the full shortest path.

Comment: The similar named `shortest_paths` function gives you the full paths as a list, but you have to specify the vertices you start from. For instance `shortest_paths(g,1)` gives you the paths from the vertex 1 to all the vertices in the graph. You can see that some paths do not start with 1; that means that the corresponding end vertex is not reachable (you get also a warning because of it).

Comment: @nicola, makes sense, but that gives reachable vertices while I only want the shortest paths. And on top of that, there's the problem as well that it doesn't give me the intermediate vertices. I'll edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: try `shortest.paths(g, weights=NA, mode="out")`, and you should get a matrix with the desired result. Unreachable nodes show up as `Inf`. By setting weights to NA shortest paths just sums up the number of edges for you, and setting `mode='out'` gives directed paths from row to column. Number of nodes between i and j will be number of edges minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

Found an alternate solution to the problem.

```
sp <- shortest_paths(g, V(g), V(g), mode = "all",
                         weights = E(g)$weight, output = "vpath")$vpath

lengths(sp)
```

This gives the exact number of vertices on that path. So for the intermediate stops it's just a matter of subtracting 2 to the value.